# Tune up utilities drive defrag ate my disk space

Tags: windows-8, defragment

Today I used Tune up drive defrag and after using it my free disk space decreased by 9 GB. Why did this happen. What can I do to recover the disk space?
Thank you.
I just found out that this is using my disk space. 
[image]

Comment: Got it. It's my free space and it's not an SSD.

Comment: Alright.  Use a tool to determine what is using your free space.  You recover your free space by removing something from your HDD

Comment: Can you tell me the tool that I should use for this purpose.

Comment: I don't make product recommendations when you have done very little research on the subject.

Comment: I just shut down the PC and the next day my space was back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you must be check your disk health state with [Hard disk sentinel](http://www.harddisksentinel.com/hdsentinel_pro_setup.zip).
It can show you how the hard drive status or the number of degrees.
In this case, if the program shows low % or high temperatures, is already one of the possible reasons that seemed nowhere to 9GB.
After you must be make a backup for important datas for the next steps.
Then I higly recomend for you start your computer with safe mode with command promt (when your computer starting press f8), and write this to command prompt:

```
chkdsk/f
```

This can be check your worng indexs and some wrong volume information.
After, if you're done with, you must find in the google this program "AVG PC Tune UP 2011", this is also a fixer tool for your system and hard disk.
You shuld be fine with this program, becouse the menu points and interfes is so sample.
And if All this not help for you, you must be backup your datas and reformating your HDD.

Comment: AVG PC tune up utilities 2014 is the program responsible for the lost desk space. :(

Comment: Yes, becouse the new version not work in perfectly...

Comment: You might want to add a warning that running the command you suggest CAN lead to data loss if the tool detects errors

Comment: OK. I'll try this.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it possible, but I use this command in 10 years and I never lose anything.

Comment: @Neo - I am at 100% data loss when I have ran `chkdsk` personally.

Comment: Then, you haven't good windows....
Only trusted source help your problem

Answer (score 0):

**"I just found out that this is using my disk space." [System Volume Information]**

[image]

Reference [About $Recycle.bin, Recycler and System Volume Information Folders in Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/about-recycler-and-system-volume-information-folder-in-xp-and-vista/)

> **The System Volume Information Folder**
>
> The System Volume Information folder is a hidden folder in the root of
>   your C drive that the Windows System Restore tool uses to store its
>   information and restore points. It’s not just System Restore data that
>   gets stored in here though and the Windows Indexing Service uses it to
>   store search databases, the Volume Shadow Copy Service creates live
>   system backup data and also Distributed Link Tracking stores database
>   information to repair shortcuts and linked documents. Check Disk logs
>   are also saved here.

**"What can I do to recover the disk space?"**

> **Deleting System Volume Information or its Files**
>
> Once you have gained ownership of the System Volume Information
>   folder, it’s then possible to access and delete any of the files
>   inside or the whole folder itself. **We highly recommend you DO NOT do
>   this for the System Volume Information folder on your Windows drive
>   (C:). As we said earlier, it contains data for many other system
>   components besides System Restore and could make Windows unstable or
>   even crash.** Besides, if you delete it from C, the whole folder will
>   simply be created again automatically.

Reference [Delete a restore point](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/delete-restore-point#1TC=windows-7)

> **You cannot delete an individual restore point, but you can either
>   delete all restore points or all but the most recent restore point.
>   Deleting restore points temporarily frees up disk space. As new
>   restore points are created, disk space will be used again.**
>
> **To delete all but the most recent restore point**
>
> 1. Open Disk Cleanup by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button. In the search box, type Disk Cleanup, and then, in the
>      list of results, click Disk Cleanup.
> 2. If prompted, select the drive that you want to clean up, and then click OK.
> 3. In the Disk Cleanup for (drive letter) dialog box, click Clean up system files. Administrator permission required If you're prompted
>      for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or
>      provide confirmation.
> 4. If prompted, select the drive that you want to clean up, and then click OK.
> 5. Click the More Options tab, under System Restore and Shadow Copies, click Clean up.
> 6. In the Disk Cleanup dialog box, click Delete.
> 7. Click Delete Files, and then click OK.